# Is it possible to change values in build.prop without editing it?

Tags: root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, ota-update, system, terminal

I want to change the line `ro.build.type` from `user` to `userdebug` in `/system/build.prop` to enable multiwindow. But this modifies the `/system` partition and will prevent OTA updates (and some apps) from working (I have a un-rooted Nexus which gets monthly updates so it can be annoying to flash).

Running `getprop ro.build.type` in Terminal Emulator returns `user` on my un-rooted Nexus.But before I ROOT I would to know if I can use `su -c setprop ro.build.type userdebug`.I will ROOT using the new systemless ROOT (which does not modify `/system`). All this is to enable the new Marshmallow multiwindow feature.

Comment: Check if this works: `su -c setprop persist.sys.debug.multi_window true`.. (Source: https://reddit.com/r/Android/comments/3o894i/psa_you_can_enable_multiwindow_without_changing/)

Comment: @GokulNC I am not rooted!

Comment: I meant to try it after flashing system-less root.

Comment: @GokulNC How about editing `/data/local.prop` . Will that work

Comment: I am new to rooting and all this kind of stuff.Also just wondering if you can hard brick your device if it has an unlocked bootloader and working fastboot because I don't think you can you can corrupt fastboot.I have heard about OTA updates bricking devices because their bootloader is locked so they can't flash a new ROM (you can fix it if it unlocked so I  enable OEM unlock in developer options on my device before updating so it doesn't brick)

Comment: @SuiciDoga - Systemless root is the way to go, for you. But please be warned that the multi-window feature in M is somewhat half done and not polished. You may very well wait for N to get released in Q3 this year. If not, you can dive in right away with N Dev Preview 4. It seems to be stable enough to run as your daily driver.

Comment: @blueren I'll wait for Dev Preview 5 since it will be the final thing which will be released later